# java decryption compatible with sjcl throws error - mac check in CCM failed

Tags: java, aes, sjcl

I am trying to decrypt on java an encrypted message that I received from client that uses sjcl for encriptyon
I use sjcl with default parameters

here is what I have so far

```
    public static void decrypt(){

    try {
        String salt="yIv/YH1+pBs=";
        String iv="xmzopU9UqwM=";
        String password="password";
        String cipherText="5xy76uy4oOIHA8PKeD3Uyjp9ex6zh449";
        //Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 10000, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CCM/NoPadding",new BouncyCastleProvider());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes()));
        cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes());

        System.out.println(cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes()));

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

from calling this method I get the next exception

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in CCM failed
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at probaDeMicrofon.AdvancedEncryptionStandard.decrypt(AdvancedEncryptionStandard.java:84)
at probaDeMicrofon.AdvancedEncryptionStandard.main(AdvancedEncryptionStandard.java:115)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: All of your input values except password (salt, iv, ciphertext) are obviously encoded in base64 and need to be decoded. Also, `Cipher.doFinal`  returns `byte[]` and printing that type is useless (see many other Qs); since it actually contains characters you can construct a `String` from it before printing. If it actually contained other data (which is could) you would need to do something else, and if you want to do something with it other than print it you might want to do something else.

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085 I decoded the input values and it's working